# Query to show old and new values from another table - query the latest ChangeDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2012.

Table History is the history of all the changes made to the values in Table A. It can have many changes done to PRICE, LOT, INTEREST, but in most cases the value is only changed once.

Table A

```
AID PRICE   LOT    INTEREST
------------------------
1   1500    9000   0.5
2   2500    20     1.5
```

Table B

```
BID AID
--------
11  1
22  2
```

Table History

```
BID     ChangeField     OldValue    NewValue   ChangeDate
------------------------------------------------------------
11      PRICE           1700        1500       1/1/22
11      LOT             10000       8000       12/15/21 
11      LOT             8000        9000       2/2/22
```

I need a query that shows Table A with the old and new values from Table History. If there are more than 1 changes, then for the Old value, get the most recent previous value. In the above example, the most recent previous value for Lot is 8000 from 2/2/22 (not 10000 from 12/15/21).

Example:

```
AID OldPRICE    NewPRICE    OldLot  NewLot  OldInterest NewInterest
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   1700        1500        8000    9000    0.5         0.5
2   2500        2500        20      20      1.5         1.5
```

This query returns OldLot = 10000 (the biggest value for Lot), instead of 8000 (the most recent previous value)

```
SELECT A.AID,
   MAX(CONVERT(numeric(30, 2),ISNULL(CASE WHEN h.ChangeField = 'LOT' THEN h.OldValue 
   END,A.LOT))) OldLot,
   MAX(CONVERT(numeric(30, 2),ISNULL(CASE WHEN h.ChangeField = 'LOT' THEN h.NewValue 
   END,A.LOT))) NewLot
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.AID = B.AID
LEFT JOIN History h ON B.BID = h.BID
WHERE H.BID = 11
GROUP BY A.AID
```

That returns below (notice OldLot = 10000 instead of 8000)

```
AID OldLot  NewLot  
--------------------
1   10000    9000
```

Thank you

Comment: So the "answer" you marked to your previous question on the same problem is not really an answer. And why do you need to convert anything? Are OldValue and NewValue stored as strings? Regardless, are you wedded to this design? A far easier, simpler approach is to simply store the complete row when changed rather than a row per value changed.

Comment: And clarify your logic / goal. Lot changed twice in your sample data but only one change is shown for the role as a whole. The very first lot value was 10000 - why is that NOT the old value?

Comment: This is a bit confusing as your example seems to just require the previous value, you're showing the current value and the last value?

Comment: I need to convert the values because columns OldValue and NewValue in table History are varchar(200) , so if I didn't convert it to numeric 8000 is bigger than 10000. On my previous question, I didn't realize the answered query doesn't work when there are more than 1 changes per Change Field.

Comment: Lot value 10000 was the original value, not the most recent value before it was changed to 9000. The previous value was 8000 before it was changed to 9000. So, I would like the OldLot to be 8000, the new lot to be 9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly you are just after the most recent history value per field which you can do using a row_number partition, then you just need to pivot the rows to columns to combine with the current values:

```
with h as (
    select b.aid, h.*, 
      Row_Number() over(partition by h.bid, h.changefield order by h.changedate desc) rn
    from history h
    join b on b.bid=h.bid
)
select a.aid,
  isnull(h.oldprice, a.price) OldPrice, a.PRICE newprice,
  isnull(h.oldLot, a.lot) OldLot, a.Lot NewLot,
  isnull(h.oldInterest, a.interest) OldInterest, a.Interest newInterest
from a
outer apply (
  select 
    max(case when changefield = 'LOT' then oldvalue end) OldLot,
    max(case when changefield = 'PRICE' then oldvalue end) OldPrice,
    max(case when changefield = 'INTEREST' then oldvalue end) OldInterest
  from h
  where h.aid = a.aid and h.rn = 1
)h
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=08fb0f81145d0c3bff614a3f59f8819f)

Also note, if you were using a more current version of SQL Server (2016+) there is inbuilt functionality for this using *system versioning* with its own extentions to t-sql for this kind of querying.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That works !